# Https connector JavaKeyStore$JKS KeyStore not available error

Tags: mule, jks

I want to poll a https endpoint with the quartz scheduler, but i keep getting keystore errors.
Using the same keystore, in the same mule-project, in the same flow, with a http-polling endpoint, works without a problem. This is in Mule 3.5.

So this works:

```
<https:polling-connector name="HTTP_Polling" cookieSpec="netscape" validateConnections="true" pollingFrequency="10000" sendBufferSize="0" receiveBufferSize="0" receiveBacklog="0" clientSoTimeout="10000" serverSoTimeout="10000" socketSoLinger="0" doc:name="HTTP Polling">
    <https:tls-client path="public_certs.jks" storePassword="password" class="sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS"/>
</https:polling-connector>

<https:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" doc:name="HTTP"  connector-ref="HTTP_Polling" host="app1.nijmegen.nl" path="Loket/prodcat/products/samenwerkendecatalogi/feed/getIndexFeedAction.do" port="443"/>
```

but with the quartz element and a normal https connector i keep getting a `Keystore not available` error

```
<https:connector name="app1-HTTPS" cookieSpec="netscape" validateConnections="true" sendBufferSize="0" receiveBufferSize="0" receiveBacklog="0" clientSoTimeout="10000" serverSoTimeout="10000" socketSoLinger="0" doc:name="HTTP-HTTPS">
    <https:tls-client path="public_certs.jks" storePassword="password" class="sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS"/>
</https:connector>
```

```
<quartz:inbound-endpoint jobName="pollExxellence" repeatInterval="0" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Quartz" cronExpression="0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *">
        <quartz:endpoint-polling-job>
            <quartz:job-endpoint ref="app1"/>
        </quartz:endpoint-polling-job>
    </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
```

Someone who knows what's going wrong?